# How does Bash parameter expansion work?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I'm trying to understand a Bash script. I stumbled upon this:

```
DIR=${1:-"/tmp"}
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:-` is actually an operator it says that if `$1` (first argument to the script) is not set or is `null` then use `/tmp` as the value of `$DIR` and if it's set assign it's value to `$DIR`.

```
DIR=${1:-"/tmp"}
```

is short for

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
        DIR='/tmp'
else
        DIR="$1"
fi
```

It can be used with any variables not just positional parameters:

```
$ echo ${HOME:-/tmp} # since $HOME is set it will be displayed.
/home/codaddict
$ unset HOME   # unset $HOME.
$ echo ${HOME:-/tmp} # since $HOME is not set, /tmp will be displayed.
/tmp
$
```

Comment: First, as Gumbo said in his answer, `:-` accounts not only for unset variable, but also for variable which expands to a null string. Use `-` (without a colon) to test only for set/unset variable. Second, your code with DIR is wrong because you did not quote the `$1` variable. As a result, if it expands to multiple fields, an error will occur.

Answer (score 8):

That syntax is [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ```
> ${parameter:-word}
> ```
>
> If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

So if `$1` is unset or null, it evaluates to `"/tmp"` and to the value of `$1` otherwise.